# Two joins on same table in SQL

Tags: alias

I've got 2 SQL tables: `NAMES` and `RELATIONSHIPS` Currently `NAMES` just has 2 columns: `name` and `name_id`. The other is a list of relationships between people in the `NAMES` table.   It has 3 columns: `primaryperson_id`, `relatedperson_id`, and `relationship_id`.  The `primaryperson_id` and `related_person_id` are `name_id`s from the `NAMES` table.  Each person in `NAMES` can have multiple entries in either the primary or related columns of `RELATIONSHIPS` (is that a many-to-many relationship?).

This query works:

```
SELECT  people.name AS 'primary', relationships.related_person_id AS relatedto
FROM relationships
JOIN people
ON people.name_id=relationships.primary_person_id 
ORDER BY people.name_id;
```

But I'd like to show a name (i.e. text) in the `relatedto` column rather than the id number.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign a *table alias* when you join tables, just like you do with the column names. Not only does it save you a lot of typing, but it makes the code a little more readable, and it solves the problem of joining the same table twice.

```
SELECT p1.name AS "primary",
       relationships.related_person_id AS relatedto,
       p2.name AS related_name
FROM people AS p1
INNER JOIN relationships AS r
    ON p1.name_id=r.primary_person_id 
INNER JOIN people AS p2
    ON p2.name_id=r.related_person_id 
ORDER BY p1.name_id;
```

In the example above, I've assigned `p1` and `p2` to the `people` table and `r` to the `relationships` table.

Note: some database platforms don't like the "AS" keyword. You can skip "AS" alltogether if you want, like so:

```
...
FROM people p1
INNER JOIN relationships r
...
```

Comment: I had to change `relationships.related_person_id AS relatedto` to `r.related_person_id AS relatedto` but otherwise it worked!  Thanks.

Comment: I'm using MS Access/OLEDB and I needed to add parentheses around the JOIN statements for this to work. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854969/sql-multiple-join-statement) on Stack Overflow for details.